# How to connect two functions so that value from one flows to the other when some event happen?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

One function receives user action:

```
function userDidSomething(whatever){
 return whatever 
}
```

now, whenever the user does that i need to be able to know that something happened in another function in another file:

```
function notifyWhenUserDidSomething(whatever){
// any time "userDidSomething" is called i want to have its return value in THIS function

}
```

These functions are in different files so I cannot just do

```
UserDidSomething(whatever){
   notifyWhenUserDoSomething(whatever)
  return whatever;
}
```

Also, assume no DOM event handling is possible....is there some way to achieve this using some callback thing or something?

Comment: You can use ES6 import and export statements, just import that function and pass it a value.

Comment: What you're asking for is an Observer Pattern. There can be many ways to achieve this, either through a library ( like jquery ) or by a small implementation of your own. See this link for an idea - https://medium.com/@patrickackerman/the-observer-pattern-with-vanilla-javascript-8f85ea05eaa8